# Database not working in VS 2015

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2015, combobox, warnings

I am using VS 2015.
I made a product category database for my combobox, the problem is the categories I put in the database is not showing the combobox.

Here is my code:

```
public AddProducts()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        comboBox1.DataSource = cse.tblProductCategories;
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Description";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "ProductCategory";

    }
```

> "tblProducts" is the table name. "Description" is the second column of the table. "ProductCategory" is the first column with key.

Whenever i run the application it runs smoothly, but then when I click the button where the combobox is from, a warning shows up that says

> "An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: Data binding directly to a store query (DbSet, DbQuery, DbSqlQuery, DbRawSqlQuery) is not supported. Instead populate a DbSet with data, for example by calling Load on the DbSet, and then bind to local data. For WPF bind to DbSet.Local. For WinForms bind to DbSet.Local.ToBindingList(). For ASP.NET WebForms you can bind to the result of calling ToList() on the query or use Model Binding, for more information see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=389592."

that is pointing at the code *"comboBox1.ValueMember = "ProductCategory";"* Then when I press continue, categories I put in the database is not showing up in my combobox.

Please help me, I'm just a student trying to learn. Thank you!

Comment: What platform is that combobobx? WPF? Winforms? Asp.net?

Comment: Platform is Winforms

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I found it myself. I added "ToList();" to my code and it worked:

```
public AddProducts()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        comboBox1.DataSource = (cse.tblProductCategories).ToList();
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Description";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "ProductCategory";

    }
```